# ASP.NET Theme on CDN

Tags: asp.net, azure, amazon-web-services, themes, cdn

We want to distribute our .NET Themes out to edge of the Cloud.

However, my research through Google and Help files tells me that ASP.NET Themes (App_Themes) must be served from a physical sub-folder of the web server folder or an IIS virtual directory; ergo: Themes cannot be served from a CDN (we are currently using AWS).  This seems a major failing and I hope that I am just going to get flamed for not researching properly, but I have to ask:

**Does someone know of a way of serving ASP.NET Themes from a different server (and URI) than the web application that uses the Themes?**

(Windows Azure could be a possibility, if it is a/the_only way to achieve this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using themes and skins you primarily style server controls. Then it doesn't make sense to have theme files in CDN, since they are processed by the server.

> ### Themes vs. Cascading Style Sheets
>
> Themes are similar to cascading style sheets in that both themes and style sheets define a set of common attributes that can be applied
>   to any page. However, themes differ from style sheets in the following
>   ways:
>
> - Themes can define many properties of a control or page, not just style properties. For example, using themes, you can specify the
>     graphics for a TreeView control, the template layout of a GridView
>     control, and so on.
> - Themes can include graphics.
> - Themes do not cascade the way style sheets do. By default, any property values defined in a theme referenced by a page's Theme
>     property override the property values declaratively set on a control,
>     unless you explicitly apply the theme using the StyleSheetTheme
>     property. For more information, see the Theme Settings Precedence
>     section above.
> - Only one theme can be applied to each page. You cannot apply multiple themes to a page, unlike style sheets where multiple style
>     sheets can be applied.

Source: [ASP.NET Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michal, but this doesn't really answer my question, and I respectfully disagree that "it doesn't make sense to have theme files in CDN".  Taking the specifics of your answer, I could re-word to say, does anyone know a way of serving ASP.Net Theme graphics files from a different server, but that would be too restrictive, so I will run with the question I have posed for now in the hope that someone does know a way this can be done.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, actually in that point you are right and you can put referenced images to CDN, no problem at all. The same might apply to CSS styles.